# i do not know how to pass an array from functtion to orderBy using angularjs when click a buttom from modal in different html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a modal (a popup panel) where i have different attributes that can be selected and placed in order from top to bottom.

I need help because i have create a function in the modal controller that returns an array of elements to sort so i can pass it to the orderBy, now the user needs to click a button in the modal so the properties are sort automatically. I do not know how to make the click button to pass the sort() function to the html that contains the list with the properties. So the click button is in different html and different controller.

Any help will be appreciated

Some code here
1. this is the array for the modal popup panel

```
$scope.items = [
   {name:'Price', selected: false, asc:false},
   {name:'Beds', selected: false, asc:false},
   {name:'Size', selected: false, asc:false},
 ];
```

2. this is the function that maps the elements that are selected only with the actual value that i want to sort (value from backend property), im returning the result array with the elements that i want to pass to orderBy

sort.js

```
$scope.applySort = function() {
    var map = {};
    map['Price'] = "tprice";
    map['Beds'] = "tbed";
    map['Size'] = "tsize";

    var result = [];
    for (var index= 0; index < $scope.items.length ; index++) {
       if ($scope.items[index].selected == true){
       result.push(($scope.items[index].asc ==true ? map[$scope.items[index].name] : "-" + map[$scope.items[index].name]));
        }
    }
    return result;
     $scope.close = close;
```

}

3. (modal popup window open from display page)that shows the modal with different li attributes where the user can selected and click function put elements selected in order, here i have a button that apply the applySort function

this is the sort.html

```
<div id="overlay">
    <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close()" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <button type="button" class="apply" ng-click="applySort()" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">apply</button>
    <h5 id="slogann">Sort properties by.....</h5>
    <div class="row">
       <ul id="list" class="task">
          <li ng-repeat="item in items" data-group = li-1 ng-click="click($index);$event.stopPropagation()" ng-class="item.selected?'test-seleted':'test-unseleted'">
          </li>

      </ul>
</div>
```

this is the display.html

```
<div ng-repeat="property in properties |orderBy: aplySort()" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 animated fadeInUp" ng-mouseover="onCardsHover(property, $event)" >
```

4. this code is from the display page where the modal opens and i want to call the orderBy from that applySort function , so the method returns the array that contains the properties that i want to sort.

this is the modal in the display.js

```
$scope.showSortModal = function() {
   ModalService.showModal({
   templateUrl: "views/modals/sort.html",
   controller:"SortCtrl",
   bodyClass: "custom-modal-open",
   scope : $scope
   }).then(function(modal) {
  //modal.element.modal();
   modal.close.then(function(result) {});

   });
};
```

The problem i have is that the applySort method is in different controller and view, the orderBy is in the display and needs to somehow get the return from that method so it can sort the properties with those attributes. I do not know how to connect the apply button in the sort.html to pass it to the orderBy

Comment: can you share your code? because it is difficult to understand your question

Comment: just put some code to clarify the question